# Maven checksum pom setting?

Tags: maven-2, checksum, pom.xml

Google has failed me and I can't find an answer even here on SO - relegating me to actually posting my first question here.

I'm trying to get the command "mvn install" to automatically generate the checksums for the artifacts and place the checksums in the repository right along with the artifacts.  Everything I've read seems to indicate it should be happening without my intervention, but all I'm getting is the artifact, a source zip, a pom, and the local metadata xml.

The pom for the project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.pkg.name</groupId>
  <artifactId>Logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/conf</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>test/conf</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
              <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.6.SEC02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.2</version>
     <type>jar</type>
     <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm sure the answer is something simple, but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.  Anyone want to answer this softball?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`install:install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) goal of the Maven Install Plugin has an optional [`createChecksum`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#createChecksum) parameter that defaults to `false`.

Either set it to `true` on the command line (as documented in [Creating Checksums](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-checksums.html)):

> ```
> mvn install -DcreateChecksum=true
> ```

Or in the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had seen the command line all over the place, but the pom configuration line seems to be "need to know" or something, because it isn't even listed on the install:install plugin pages on apache.com.Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: @ogradyjd: You're welcome. BTW, the POM configuration is simply derived from the documentation of the mojo (if a goal admits a parameter `foo`, you can configure it with a `<foo>bar</foo>` inside a `<configuration>` element). A Usage page is welcome though.

Comment: This option was removed in 3.0.0+ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-143