# Minecraft-Forge: JSON file hashes

Tags: c#, json, hash, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently working on a **launcher** for minecraft with forge.
The problem i'm facing now is about **hashes**. Vanilla's hashes are SHA1 Hashes, and that's ok.(here for example https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10/1.7.10.json)
I have to check hashes for forge too and i have this JSON file: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/FML/blob/master/jsons/1.7.10-rel.json.
As you can see for each library there is a checksums field with two values.
Now my question is: What are they? I imagine they are some kind of hashes of the files, not the names. I tried to check both SHA1 and MD5 but they are not the same.
I don't even understand why there are two values.
Does someone have an explanation for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307146/verification-of-dependency-authenticy-in-maven-pom-based-automated-build-systems#3309802 might answer your question. not entirely sure

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, these two checksums are MD5 and SHA1 respectively. They are related to the Maven repository that the JSON file references as per the ***url*** tag for each library. The Forge artifacts likely followed this: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/#checksumasc

In short, the previous URL explains briefly how a Maven repository works and references these 2 checksums as download verification. Another reference to the creation of Maven checksums also points to them coming in pairs: [Maven checksum pom setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865343/maven-checksum-pom-setting)

Here's a plugin that can interact with the checksums: http://checksum-maven-plugin.nicoulaj.net/

tl;dr These are Maven repository checksums that comes in a MD5 *and* SHA1 pair.
In a C# setting, there are a number of options to do verify both:

- https://dzone.com/articles/generating-md5-and-sha1

  ```cs
      public static void ComputeMD5Hash(object filePath)
      {
          using (var stream = new FileStream((string)filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
          {
              using (var md5gen = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
              {
                  md5gen.ComputeHash(stream);
                  Program.MD5Hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5gen.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- [Calculate MD5 checksum for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file)