# Can I force Maven to verify downloaded jars?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm having a lot of problems lately with Maven 3.5.0 downloading corrupted JARs.

I don't know why, it could be a problem with my workplace's network, the repos we use, or just my computer. Anyway, usually it's easy to solve them, I just need to delete the jar from .m2/repository and force a new download. But it's making me waste *a lot* of time, specially because sometimes I can't tell there is a problem at all until I'm already deploying the war to the server.

Is there any command prompt, or a parameter I could add to my settings file, so that Maven would check the integrity of each downloaded jar and pom, and redownload them automatically if needed?

Comment: By default the checksum policy is set to `warn` so you should set this to `fail` see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll set it to `fail`, although it probably will help only with the Central repo. The other ones I use are corporate and government maintained repositories... and [seeing as Maven doesn't generate the checksums by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865343/maven-checksum-pom-setting) with a `install`, I doubt there will be any created.

Comment: For SNAPSHOT's that's true otherwise your configuration is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there were some bugs in Maven 3.5.0 that causes corrupt jars to be uploaded to your Maven repository. I would suggest you update to the latest Maven 3.5.x version and look if that fixes your problem, because I think Maven always verifies the downloaded jars.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update to 3.5.4 and see if it makes any improvement (along with the `fail` option suggested in the comments). But I'm not uploading artifacts to any repository, just downloading them to my .m2 folder.

Comment: @funfried can you be more specific here which bugs you are talking about?

Comment: @khmarbaise I wasn't able to find the ticket for this bug, but I also think I mixed it up with corrupted checksum files when deploying jars to a maven repository.